# return future from onComplete scala

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

An **exercise on forComprehension**, doesn't compile since returns Unit instead of Future[User]

(the task is to read using DAO and create new user using 2 parents)

I'm trying to return Future[User] from onComplete but fails (returns Unit).

```
def unbornUsingForComp(fatherId: String, motherId: String): Future[User] = {

  val fatherUser: Future[Option[User]] = usersDao.read(fatherId)
  val motherUser: Future[Option[User]] = usersDao.read(motherId)

  val combinedLastName = for {
    r1 <- fatherUser
    r2 <- motherUser
  } yield (r1, r2)

  combinedLastName.onComplete {
    case Success(x) => {
      (x._1, x._2) match {
        case (Some(u1), Some(u2)) => usersDao.create(User("JustRandomId", "JustRandomFirstName", u1.lastName + " - " +u2.lastName))
        case _ => throw new Exception("One or more of the parents not Found")
      }
    }
    case Failure(_) => {
      throw new Exception("Exception raised inside the for comp.")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`onComplete`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html#onComplete[U](f:scala.util.Try[T]=%3EU)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):Unit) by design returns `Unit` which executes a side-effect and then discards

```
// Note that the returned value of `f` will be discarded.
def onComplete[U](f: Try[T] => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

You are likely after something like

```
combinedLastName
  .map { x => // do stuff with x }
  .recover { case e => // handle exception }
```

Comment: "Future[Future[User]]" is usually solved by using `flatMap` instead of `map`. In other words, ff the function you provide to `map` returns a `Future`, you usually want `flatMap` instead.